# How to get text from label tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML code:

```
<label id = "lblID"><input type="checkbox"/> some text here</label>
```

How can I get the text from the **label** tag using javascript?

Comment: I need to retrieve only the text without input element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to exclude the checkbox

```
var text=document.getElementById('lblID').textContent;
console.log(text); // some text here
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7m26uc9/)

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript's `textContent` method.  This will extract ONLY the text, and no checkbox.

```js
alert(document.getElementById('lblID').textContent);
```

```html
<label id = "lblID"><input type="checkbox"/> some text here</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

To only  get the text (not the `input`), you can use:

```
document.getElementById('lblID').childNodes[1]
```

Since your label has 2 children, and the text is the second one.

Answer (score -2):

By using the "textContent"

var lbltext = document.getElementById('lblID').textContent;